# Move customized document library

Tags: document-library, custom-form, folder

I have a customized document library on a site but I have to move it to another site.
How can I do this (and keep meta-datas, and form skeleton).

Comment: Seen this famous powershell blog: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Copy-all-SharePoint-Files-0999c53f although I'm not sure about your preferences about form skeleton. A lot of more comfort bring along some 3rd party tools like Sharegate

Answer (score 0):

Check this blog which lets you how to move/migrate document/files from one location to another whilst preserving its metadata properties and version history: http://expert-advice.org/sharepoint/movemigrate-sharepoint-list-itemsdocuments-metadata-version-history/

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)